# Как поменять местами самый большой элемент с самым маленьким

Tags: алгоритм, c++

В общем ситуация такая, имеется бинарное дерево, нужно поменять местами самый большой элемент с самым маленьким? Как это сделать?

Comment: В вопросе не хватает исполняемого С++ кода, который пытается поменять местами крайние элементы в специфичном бинарном дереве, выбранном для примера, и описанием успешной работы программы и что происходит вместо этого, например, "программа должна напечатать `-1, 10`, а вместо этого в выводе segfault". Не нужно весь код, который есть, в вопрос добавлять; лучше добавить минимальный пример (возможно написанный специально для вопроса), который можно скомпилировать и запустить, чтобы увидеть, в чём проблема.

Comment: @greeedylol, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Предположим, что узлы дерева описаны так:

```
struct tree_node {
  struct tree_node *left, // к поддереву с меньшими ключами
                   *right;
  int key;     // тип может быть и другим
  void *data;  // аналогично.
};
```

Поскольку самый большой ключ в двоичном дереве будет крайним правым, а самый маленький, наоборот, то алгоритм очевиден --

идите по дереву от корня влево и найдите родителя самого маленького. Запомните указатель на него.

Затем идите вправо и найдите родителя самого большого.

Остается поменять два указателя в этих элементах.

**Обновление**

[[[[@jfs](/users/23044/jfs)](/users/23044/jfs)](/users/23044/jfs)](/users/23044/jfs), конечно, однозначно понять, что имел в виду автор, говоря:

```
 нужно поменять местами самый большой элемент с самым маленьким
```

нельзя.

Я имел в виду (`pmin` -- указатель на родителя маленького и `pmax` на родителя самого большого)

```
 typeof(pmin) t = pmin->left;
 pmin->left = pmax->right;
 pmax->right = t;
```

Что же касается C++ вообще, то я поддерживаю [т.з. Линуса](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus) , хотя и признаю, что это уже неизбежное зло.

**Обновление 2**

[[@dzhioev](/users/552/dzhioev)](/users/552/dzhioev), и в самом деле, это же не из чего не следует.

Для произвольного дерева находим адреса указателей на сами минимальный и максимальный элементы за один рекурсивный обход, а потом меняем их значения (это будут указатели на поля в узлах родителей),

а второй комментарий (с текстом "перестанет быть правильным") считаем не относящимся к делу.

**Обновление 3**

[[[[@jfs](/users/23044/jfs)](/users/23044/jfs)](/users/23044/jfs)](/users/23044/jfs), да, утро вечера мудренее...

Согласен, все мои комментарии неправильные. Если надо переставлять поддеревья, то все не просто.

Например, представьте вырожденное дерево поиска. Учтем даже, что можно поменять указатель на корень (теперь это будет max). Все равно остается вопрос к какому из линков  цеплять min и как корректировать линки в max (и др. тоже).

---

Однако, у Вас совершенно тривиальный подход. Вы же меняете только содержимое узлов, оставляя структуру дерева нетронутой.

---

Комментарии у меня закончились (один уже удалил), так что, видимо, оставим задачку с Вашим решением.

Comment: @avp: В  С++ можно без `void*` обойтись, если шаблоном воспользоваться. Если хранить данные в узле по значению и обмен значений может быть дорогим, то можно сами узлы (указатели) обменивать (а их детей на место передвинуть), например:

      // swap nodes
      std::swap(min, max);
      // put children back
      std::swap(min->left, max->left);
      std::swap(min->right, max->right);

Comment: @avp, почему вы решили, что у автора дерево поиска? Я так понял, про произвольное бинарное дерево идет речь.

Comment: @avp: 1. Вопрос имеет тег `c++`, поэтому решение должно описывать `c++` в первую очередь. 2. Не достаточно `pmin->left`, `pmax-right` поменять, см. "put children back" выше. Можно поиграться с [кодом](http://ideone.com/kK2uGq), вот [соответствующая картинка](http://imgur.com/H4ZI4Xv).

Comment: @avp: Если нужно переставить поддеревья тогда всё ещё проще (достаточно, `swap(min, max)`, где min, max имеют тип `NodePtr`. 

Вы правы, первый мой пример вырожденные деревья (корень имеет меньше двух детей) не поддерживал. Но его легко поправить (я обновил код). 

[Я добавил поддержку ввода дерева из stdin](http://ideone.com/yTpJkw). Так что если найдёте пример дерева, когда код ломается, то можно просто ссылочку с соответствующем вводом/выводом предоставить.